# Unable to remove jdk 8 from windows

Tags: java, java-8, java-11, openjdk-11

I have JDK 1.8.0_261 , JDK 1.8.0_265 installed on my server.

When I un-installed both these JDK's from the control panel, the folder structure of JDK 1.8.0_261 is automatically removed from my Java installed directory but for JDK 1.8.0_265 & JRE8 the folders are not removed.

I even rebooted the server still the folders are not deleted. I am unable to rename the same.

Currently I am using openJDK11 , all the registry keys & environment variables are pointing to 11.

I suspect that some service is still using jdk8 , I want to uninstall jdk 8 from my server completely , please suggest how can I check which process is using jdk8 and how can I remove it completely.

In the Resource monitor > CPU > Associated handle when I searched the folder name of jdk1.8.0_261 then it gave couple of processes java.exe which are using that folder files ... but how can I find which application is using that java.
Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

The Process Monitor tool can tell you what process has a file open.  When you try to delete a file and Windows claims that some process has it open, selfishly keeping the vital information of which process to itself, try this tool:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

(There is a lot more to it than just finding which process has a handle to a file.)

That will help you identify any service that is use the older JRE.

Comment: I am afraid if I am allowed to install this on my server. Is there anything else by which I could get to know which service is using java 8.

Comment: You can run the Process Monitor directly from https://live.sysinternals.com/Procmon.exe without installing it. But this answer seems to confuse Process Monitor with [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) (https://live.sysinternals.com/procexp64.exe). The former allows to see lock operations when the happen, the latter allows to find the already existing locks.